# MySQL VS Postgres/POSTGIS spatial database support

Tags: mysql, postgresql, spatial, postgis

We're building a small-sized GIS Web application (as a school project) right now.

In terms of spatial database support and capabilities, which is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check it out for yourself, you know what you're looking for in your GIS-application:
http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=sqlserver2008_postgis_mysql_compare

In general PostGIS is much more mature and is very flexible. You can create any function, operator, index type or what so ever. It has (almost) no limits.

Answer (score 0):

Postgis+PostgreSQL is much better than mysql. mysql supports datatypes of spatial database but there are no/limited spatial functions. postgis offers you lots of functions which will help you and will make your task easier.